# How to prove that for all non-negative $\forall x\in\mathbb R: x\ge \frac{\ln^2(1+x+\sqrt{2x})}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms, taylor-expansion, real-numbers

I'm trying to prove that for all non-negative $\forall x\in\mathbb R:$
$$x\ge \frac{\ln^2(1+x+\sqrt{2x})}{2}.$$

You can think of it as a tighter inequality than the useful $x\ge \ln(1+x)$ or $e^x\ge 1+x$.

Using the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+y)$, for $y=x+\sqrt{2x}$, gets ugly fast and it's hard to make anything out of it.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I meant $(\ln())^2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be written as

$$\sqrt{2x}\geq\ln(1+x+\sqrt{2x}), \quad x\geq0$$

raising both sides to the exponential function, the relation becomes

$$\text{e}^{\sqrt{2x}}\geq1+x+\sqrt{2x}$$

using the taylor expansion for the exponential function (and specifically writing out terms which will cancel with those on the right side), we have

$$1+\sqrt{2x}+\frac{2x}{2}+\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{n/2}}{n!}\geq1+x+\sqrt{2x}$$

which simplifies to

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{n/2}}{n!}\geq0$$

which is certainly true for $x\geq0$.

Comment: Perfect, elegant and simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{2x}=t$.

Thus, $t\leq0$, $\ln\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)\geq0$ and we need to prove that
$$t^2\geq\ln^2\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)$$ or $f(t)\geq0,$ where
$$f(t)=t-\ln\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}\right).$$
But, $$f'(t)=1-\frac{1+t}{1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}}\geq0,$$ which says
$$f(t)\geq f(0)=0$$ and we are done!